# Lost NCIndex (NDF) file to one of my DBs. Can anything be done with just the MDF? Any reads possible at all?

Tags: sql-server, non-clustered-index

Lost NCIndex (NDF) file to one of my DBs. Can anything be done with just the MDF? Any reads possible at all?
I assume not, but figured I'd ask anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. The .MDF has what is basically a manifest of all the files it needs for a complete database.  If one of those files is missing, like your .ndf, then it won't attach.  There may be a third party tool for this but I'm guessing it won't be free or cheap.